# TFS 2010 RC: How to fail a build for low code coverage?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

How can I cause a build to fail when code coverage is below a certain threshold?

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that the code coverage results file that MSTest produces is in a binary format.  However, assuming that things haven't changed too much in VS2010, you should be able to use this utility to convert it into an XML file:

http://codeexperiment.com/file.axd?file=2008%2f9%2fCodeCoverageConverter.zip

NOTE: You'll probably need to recompile it against the VS2010 version of 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Analysis.dll.

You can then use your preferred method of parsing that XML file, doing the maths for each of the instrumented assemblies to calculate an overall coverage ratio.  The XPaths you're interested in (at least for VS2008) are:

```
/CoverageDSPriv/Module/LinesCovered
/CoverageDSPriv/Module/LinesNotCovered
```

If you want to do that last step in pure MSBuild, then the 'XmlRead' and 'Math' tasks contained within the MSBuild Community Tasks library should be sufficient:

http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/

Once you have the overall ratio in an MSBuild property, you then simply use a conditional  task to break the build if that number is lower than your desired threshold.

```
<Error Condition=" $(CodeCoverageRatio) &lt; $(MinCodeCoverage) "
       Text="Code Coverage is below required threshold." />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is very likely a way to do this with a build task (particularly if you are willing to roll your own).  Hopefully someone will post some sample code for you.

If not, I have been impressed with [NDepend](http://ndepend.com/) for this type of task.  You can write in a very self-explanatory, SQL-like syntax to determine all sorts of metrics about your code and warn or fail a build based on thresholds.

Examples:

```
WARN IF Count > 0 IN SELECT METHODS WHERE CodeWasChanged AND PercentageCoverage <  95
WARN IF Count > 0 IN SELECT METHODS WHERE IsPublic AND IsInOlderBuild AND WasRemoved
```

Answer (score 0):

Ancient question, but not marked as answered. Take a look at [this](http://scrumdod.blogspot.com.au/2011/04/fail-build-if-code-coverage-is-low.html)